# How to sort the template specialisation for iterators?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I'm writing a `partition` function and it's specialization for `Bidirectional` and `Forward` Iterators.

And I'm not sure If the order affects the result, that is if these two versions are different.

**1st**

```
template< class BIter, class UnaryPredicate>
BIter __partition( BIter first,
                   BIter last,
                   UnaryPredicate pred,
                   std::bidirectional_iterator_tag);

template<typename FIter, typename UnaryPredicate>
FIter __partition(FIter first,
                  FIter last,
                  UnaryPredicate pred,
                  std::forward_iterator_tag);

template<typename FIter, typename UnaryPredicate>
FIter newton::partition(FIter first,
                        FIter last,
                        UnaryPredicate pred)
{
  return newton::__partition(first, last, pred, std::__iterator_category(first));
}
```

**2nd**

```
template<typename FIter, typename UnaryPredicate> FIter
__partition(FIter first,
            FIter last,
            UnaryPredicate pred,
            std::forward_iterator_tag);

template< class BIter, class UnaryPredicate>
BIter __partition(BIter first,
                  BIter last,
                  UnaryPredicate pred,
                  std::bidirectional_iterator_tag);

template<typename FIter, typename UnaryPredicate>
FIter newton::partition(FIter first,
                        FIter last,
                        UnaryPredicate pred)
{
  return newton::__partition(first, last, pred, std::__iterator_category(first));
}
```

I see that gcc, llmv, etc.  use the 2nd version but... I read that the compiler uses the first function that it's prototype fits.

and is not the case that `Bidirectional Iter` will fit with `Forward Iter` and then use that function instead of the specialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the order doesn't matter.

If the category parameter is exactly `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag` one function is a better match than one requiring a conversion to a base class.

Comment: Could be interesting to explain how compiler matches the better one, I comment on another answer what I believe happens. first try to fit `random_it` if not `bidirectional_it` and so on

Comment: It might be interesting, but the [Overloading clause](http://eel.is/c++draft/#over) in the language standard is 30 pages long. Will not try to write up a short summary of that.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I read that the compiler uses the first function that it's prototype fits.

Wow there! That's not true. The compiler performs [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) to find the best candidate for a function call, no matter what order they were in before.

Now of course, if you have a function right in the middle between the two, you wouldn't be able to call the second one (assuming you don't have a declaration for the second), but this is not the case here, as the two overloads are known wherever you call them.

> and is not the case that `Bidirectional Iter` will fit with `Forward Iter` and then use that function instead of the specialized?

In this case no, because the code is using a technique called tag dispatching. The "tags" are completely independent, and are often just an empty class `struct some_tag {};` (not in this case though). If this were not the case, then still no, because overload resolution still happens and even though a bidirectional iterator can be converted to a forward iterator, there is still the overload which doesn't require any conversion which is a better match.

Comment: `The "tags" are completely independent` Wow there! That's not true.

Comment: `Now of course, if you have a function right in the middle between the two, you wouldn't be able to call the second one` also is not true, I test it right now.

Comment: @MoisesRojo I'm talking in the general case. Iterators tags are not completely independent, yes.

Comment: apparetly the compiler find the best candidate, thats is true, and the order doesn't affect the output, And that is all what I need, but Still don't understand how works.

Comment: @MoisesRojo I really want to see an example where you can call a function that has not been declared yet :) How what works? Overload resolution?

Comment: Because I have the prototypes in another file.

Comment: @MoisesRojo Ah, I assumed you didn't. Fixed thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> I read that the compiler uses the first function that it's prototype fits.

Nope: it forms a set of possible candidate functions - these are functions with the right name that *could* match the arguments at your call site. Then it decides (or tries to decide) which is the best match.

This is called [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) (and *name lookup*, and the other things linked at the top of that page).

> ... is not the case that `Bidirectional Iter` will fit with `Forward Iter`

Sort of.

You're combining two things:

1. the (conceptual) relationship between iterator categories (BidirectionalIterator extends ForwardIterator etc. as in the table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)) with
2. the relationship between the [iterator category tags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags).

That is, you can *logically* say that a BidirectionalIterator *is-a* ForwardIterator, *and* `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag` is-a `std::forward_iterator_tag`, and both your overloads

```
Iter partition(Iter first, Iter last, UnaryPredicate pred,
               std::forward_iterator_tag);
Iter partition(Iter first, Iter last, UnaryPredicate pred,
               std::bidirectional_iterator_tag);
```

are candidates, *but* for a bidirectional iterator, the second overload is a better match according to the **Ranking of implicit conversion sequences** section of the linked page (it's an exact match, which as you'd expect is the best you can get).

So, we can say more precisely that there is no ambiguity between your two overloads.

Comment: Actually, they are convertible. `struct random_access_iterator_tag : public bidirectional_iterator_tag { };`

Comment: If not find a "random_access_iterator_tag" then uses `bidirectional_iterator_tag`

Comment: I test it with the example of your link [iterator category tags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) just comment the `RIter` version and vector will use `bidirectional_iter`

Comment: I think all what happened it's that if you use `struct random_access_iterator_tag : public bidirectional_iterator_tag { };` first try fit `random_access_iterator_tag` in all functions, if not then try to fit `bidirectional_iterator_tag` and so on.

Comment: The behaviour is well described on that page I linked - all the viable candidates are ranked according to how closely their parameter lists match the arguments passed (roughly how _few_ implicit conversion are needed)